# Fundamentals of cross-compiling (with CMake)

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am getting into cross-compiling (raspberry Pi stuff), and although I've been reading [a](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/iot_and_hardware/9781838821043/2/ch02lvl1sec19/using-cmake-as-a-build-system) [bunch](https://medium.com/@enes.ozturk645/cross-compiling-with-cmake-and-vscode-9ca4976fdd1) [of](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) [tutorials](https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2019/09/cmake-example-for-cross-compiling-and.html), I still don't get it.

Here is a typical `toolchain.cmake` file, as described in most of these examples:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/devel/rasp-pi-rootfs)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /home/devel/stage)

set(tools /home/devel/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

My first question: why do  I even need a toolchain in the first place? Reading [some other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325096/cross-compilers) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031194/what-is-cross-compiler-and-cross-platform), cross-compilers are just compilers that can target a different platform (e.g. I have a specific x86-64 machine, but I am asking my compiler to generate arm instructions for a different machine with a different set of registers). Can't I just pass `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/../arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` and some `-march` options to CMake and call it a day?

Assuming I really need the toolchain file shown above, why would I need all these `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_` commands? I thought the whole point of cross-compiling was that the entire compilation process would take place on my host computer, and I would only need to copy the executable to the target machine. I understand it will need to find some .dlls on the target system (which I assume is what the `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY` option is for), but why would it need to find headers there?

Comment: Most of what the extra instructions do is prevent CMake from picking up headers and libraries from your host system (because they are probably the wrong architecture but definitely **not** under control of the build process). Imagine the fireworks if CMake statically linked your ARM program  with a  `libz.a` for your host system (probably x86_64 since you're cross-compiling).

Comment: But what I don't understand is that everything will need to be on my host system, no? the headers/libraries might be special arm versions, but they will still have to be there. You mean that it will prevent CMake from looking at default locations like /usr/lib/, etc?

Comment: Yes. the CMAKE_SYSROOT is the **only** place where CMake (and your compiler) will look for headers and libraries.

Comment: These toolchain files look very CMake-2-ishy. I understand how you would want to tie yourself to a given target, but this feels like tying myself to a given host, hence suppressing most of the good things that CMake brings in the first place. What's your take on this?

Comment: Toolchain files are supposed to be generated by whatever cross sdk you install so it is okay that they are fairly rigid. See crosstool-NG for example.

Comment: so you mean I should not write this toolchain file myself, but instead it should be provided as part of `arm-linux-gnueabihf`? (in my case)

Comment: Ideally, yes. Writing it yourself was a good reflex, it insulates the code you compile from any cross compilation concerns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217946/discussion-between-touloudou-and-botje).